# Android MediaPlayer prepareAsync is failing on Galaxy SIII with Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, streaming

I'm trying to listen to a stream from an android device. 
Listening to this stream works well on all devices i tested (galaxy s I, Sony etc) but for some reason  not on Galaxy SIII android 4.1.2

I have a wrapper class to control the media player but the code translates into this standard code:

```
   mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
   mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://46.105.122.141:3634/");

   mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
  mediaPlayer.prepareAsnyc();
```

So, this works well on all other devices i tested but on Galaxy SIII after ~30 seconds in `prepareAsync` i get a Media error (-1, 1004) prepare failed error.

If i change the stream URL with a local radio

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://stream2.srr.ro:8000/");
```

streaming works fine also in galaxy sIII.

The only differences i see between the two streams

`http://46.105.122.141:3634/`

`http://stream2.srr.ro:8000/`

1. is that one one provides the IP and the other one provides a domain name.
2. Port is different (3024vs 8000)

I can't figure out why this doesn t work on galaxy SIII.

Can you please help?

Thank you!

Dan

EDIT:

Here are the logs : 
I see the "This is not a DRM content" which i don't know what it means.

There's the "cache has reached EOS, prepare is done." message.

Any ideas what can be the cause?

```
06-19 21:57:32.180: V/AwesomePlayer(1919): setDataSource_l: Audio(1), Video(0)
06-19 21:57:32.180: I/AwesomePlayer(1919): AwesomePlayer::setDataSource_l():: This is not a DRM content
06-19 21:57:32.180: I/OMXCodec(1919): Create() mime = audio/mpeg, isAlpAudio = 1
06-19 21:57:32.185: D/dalvikvm(2278): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 24% free 45614K/59911K, paused 108ms, total 109ms
06-19 21:57:32.185: W/SignalStrength(2643): getGsmLevel=4
06-19 21:57:32.190: W/SignalStrength(2643): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 11 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
06-19 21:57:32.190: W/SignalStrength(2643): getGsmLevel=4
06-19 21:57:32.190: W/SignalStrength(2643): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 11 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
06-19 21:57:32.190: I/OMXCodec(1919): Successfully allocated and configured OMX node 'OMX.SEC.MP3.Decoder , mIsALPrunning =0'
06-19 21:57:32.190: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2643): onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 11 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4 level=4
06-19 21:57:32.190: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(2643): refreshSignalCluster: data=0 bt=false
06-19 21:57:32.190: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(2643): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
06-19 21:57:32.190: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(2643): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
06-19 21:57:32.190: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(2643): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
06-19 21:57:32.200: W/SignalStrength(2278): getGsmLevel=4
06-19 21:57:32.210: W/SignalStrength(2278): getLevel=4 (SignalStrength: 11 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm|lte 4)
06-19 21:57:32.210: I/ActivityManager(2278): Process com.google.android.apps.maps (pid 18691) (adj 8) has died.
06-19 21:57:32.215: I/ActivityManager(2278): Process com.facebook.katana (pid 16373) (adj 8) has died.
06-19 21:57:32.240: W/SignalStrength(2278): getGsmDbm=-91
06-19 21:57:32.240: W/SignalStrength(2278): getDbm=-91
06-19 21:57:32.240: W/SignalStrength(2278): getGsmAsuLevel=11
06-19 21:57:32.240: W/SignalStrength(2278): getAsuLevel=11
06-19 21:57:32.295: D/AwesomePlayer(1919): cache has reached EOS, prepare is done.
06-19 21:57:32.295: W/AwesomePlayer(1919): abortPrepare() mIsAsyncPrepare (1), err (-2147483648)
06-19 21:57:32.295: V/AwesomePlayer(1919): notifyListner_l() msg (100-MEDIA_ERROR), ext1 (1), ext2 (-2147483648)
06-19 21:57:32.295: E/AwesomePlayer(1919): return http streaming network error
06-19 21:57:32.295: V/MediaPlayerService(1919): [238] notify (0x41f61fa8, 100, 1, -1004)
06-19 21:57:32.410: V/MediaPlayer(19075): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
06-19 21:57:32.410: E/MediaPlayer(19075): error (1, -1004)
06-19 21:57:32.410: V/MediaPlayer(19075): signal application thread
06-19 21:57:32.410: V/MediaPlayer(19075): prepare complete - status=1
```

Comment: Do you know what the format/encoding of the stream is?

Comment: @KenWolf Yes it's mp3 16 kbps

Answer (score 0):

> 06-19 21:57:32.295: V/MediaPlayerService(1919): [238] notify (0x41f61fa8, 100, 1, -1004)

I came across this exact scenario today, and my problem was that I was **behind a firewall** that did not allow one traffic on one of the streaming ports.